# Lightbulb problem

Tags: probability

Suppose we have 100 light bulbs of which 20 are defective. Suppose we draw two bulbs at random without replacement.

What is the probability that the second bulb is defective?

Comment: You can guess. I am sure you can. Hint: the fact that the bulb happens to come out second in order of selection does not affect its probability of being defective.

Comment: But if the first bulb selected is defective, then the probability of the second bulb being defective is 19/99, however if the first bulb isn't defective, then the probability of the second one being defective is 20/99. This is where i'm getting confused.

Comment: So if you find that knowing the defectivity of the first light bulb confuses your computation, just ignore this hypothetic knowledge, which the question does not give you anyway. Knowing the defectivity of the third light bulb drawn (which might happen, later) would also influence your odds, but you are not going to let your computation be bothered about that eventuality either.

Comment: Compute the probability that the *third* bulb drawn is defective the "long" way by cases bbb, bgb, gbb, ggb. After some pain you will get $\frac{20}{100}$. That will give incentive to *see* that the probability the $k$-th is bad is $\frac{20}{100}$.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a probability tree with D=defective and N=non-defective

$$\begin{cases}D\rightarrow&\begin{cases}D\\N\end{cases}\\{}\\N\rightarrow&\begin{cases}D\\N\end{cases}\end{cases}$$

Now take into account that

$$P(D)=\frac{20}{100}=\frac15\;,\;\;P(N)=1-\frac15=\frac45$$

and now check all the branches that lead you to D in the second (rightmost) last branch. Add the products of probabilities on each single branch and the answer must be

$$\frac1{25}+\frac4{25}=\frac15$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The first bulb is defective with a probability of $\frac{20}{100}=0.2$. If the first one is defective, the probability for the second one being defective as well is $\frac{19}{99}$. If the first one isn't defective, the  probability for the second one being defective as well is $\frac{20}{99}$.

Thus, we end up with
$$\frac{20}{100} \frac{19}{99} + \frac{80}{100}\frac{20}{99} = \frac{380 + 1600}{9900}= \frac{380 + 1600}{9900}=0.2.$$

I'm sure that there is a more direct way.

Comment: Ah great, makes sense! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The ordered couple where the second bulb is not defecttive are $80 \cdot 99 $.

The total number of ordered couple is $100 \cdot 99 $.

So your probability is $$1- \frac{80\cdot 99}{100 \cdot 99} = 0,2 $$

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that any consideration of the first lightbulb draw is completely irrelevant and out of place (since an *ordered* pair is drawn, no confusion between the two bulbs drawn is possible). After drawing the pair with your eyes closed, but back the first into the lot and mix so that you cannot find it back (be careful not to break any bulbs, though this would not effect the odds for the remaining second bulb). Then open your eyes and look at the second. In the end you have just drawn one bulb and looked at it; the rummaging around with the other bulbs is irrelevant. So your odds are just those that any randomly selected bulb in the original collection would be defective.

Of course you *can* do more complicated analyses that do involve the first bulb, and why not others as well. The final outcome should however always be that of the simpler anaylis.